Spring JPA - How to reload Parent and its Child entities after saving them within the same transaction
In my service class I'm trying to update an entity(and its many children) and want to use the updated record in the same transaction. Data is being updated in the table but context is not being updated even after calling EntityManager's flush(), clear() or refresh().
I have a one-to-many bidirectional relation between the Question and Answer entity.
I've got a common Utility class that is supposed to provide basic util methods. The idea is to have methods that take interfaces as passed arguments and perform some common logic to minimize duplication among virtually similar entities.
Util Method includes:
    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public boolean updateAnswer(IQuestionEntity quesEntity, List<String> answerValues) {

    // Does perform its logic, save,update,remove record
    return true;
    }


    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void validateSurveyQuestion(IQuestionEntity iQuestionEntity) {
    // update record
    }


Now in the service class below, I've commented out the EntityManager's calls as non of them reflect the change that has already been made in the DB, and the Persistence Context is not being updated with the updated results.
So let's say if the Question has one child Answer and is updated with another entry. Data does get updated in the answer table when the following method returns.
    Boolean ansUpdated = util.updateAnswer(headerSurveyQuestion, answerValues);

And before calling the second util method I want to use the updated records. I.E with two Answers but it still shows one. However, I can confirm data has already persisted.
Service Method:
    public void updateAnswer(Long headerSurveyQuestionId, List<String> answerValues) {
        HeaderSurveyQuestion headerSurveyQuestion = headerSruveyQuestionRepo.findById(headerSurveyQuestionId).get();
        int size = headerSurveyQuestion.getAnswers().size();
        Boolean ansUpdated = util.updateAnswer(headerSurveyQuestion, answerValues); //  <---- Table does get updated when this call returns
        String ansText = headerSurveyQuestion.getAnswers().get(0).getTextAnswer();
//      headerSurveyQuestion = headerSruveyQuestionRepo.findById(headerSurveyQuestionId).get();
//      entityManager.flush(); 
//      entityManager.clear();
//      headerSruveyQuestionRepo.f
//      entityManager.refresh(headerSurveyQuestion);
//      headerSurveyQuestion = headerSruveyQuestionRepo.findById(headerSurveyQuestionId).get();
        headerSurveyQuestion.getAnswers().size();
        size = headerSurveyQuestion.getAnswers().size();
        util.validateSurveyQuestion(headerSurveyQuestion);  //   <---- Still points to old record (I want the updated records for parent and referenced child entities)
        
    }

The service class is annotated with @Transactional and Both util methods too.
It's a Bidirectional relationship between Question and Answer entities.
QUESTION: (I've tried FetchType Lazy and Eager,  Also checked Cascade All, remove too)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "surveyQuestion", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<HeaderSurveyAnswer> answers;
    

ANSWER:
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_survey_question_id")
    private HeaderSurveyQuestion surveyQuestion;


The first thing I would do is to enable transactions logs to see how transactions are being created. See the properties to enable here: https://github.com/silver-mx/spring-demos/blob/main/spring-data-jpa-demo/src/main/resources/application.properties#L25.

Then I have a question, why do you utility methods use  @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)? Should not them be running inside the same transaction and by doing that keep you cache updated? This would avoid your issue right?

They are set to TxType.REQUIRES_NEW to save/update the records that are meant to be updated by these methods. It does it in the new transaction and suspends the service class transaction until it returns. And that's what I need. So when the method returns the changes made within util methods get committed and tables get updated. If I keep the default (i.e remove REQUIRES_NEW) then changes get committed when the service method returns.
Problem I'm facing is that the reference child entire's data are not getting refreshed before calling the 2nd method although changes are committed in table.

could you try calling headerSruveyQuestionRepo.saveAndFlush(headerSurveyQuestion) before returning from your update answer method.
Unlike save(), the saveAndFlush() method flushes the data immediately in the db. We need to use this method when our business logic needs to read the saved changes at a later point during the same transaction, but before the commit.
